# CellForRowAt not running until pull down

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

So I have an array that is being populated with user posts and then I want to populate that in a tableview based on the type of post it is. So there are 2 different cell types. When I run it, it displays 2 of the cells, but the third is hidden until you pull down the tableview. Once you pulldown the cellforrowat gets called again and works normally. The cell is out of order, however, placing it at the top instead of as the third cell as it should be.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //print("postArr here", postsArr)
    print(postID)
    //print("******0", postsArr[0])
    //print("******1", postsArr[1])
    //print("******2", postsArr[2])
    print("in tView")
    //timesRun += 1
    //let numPosts = postID.count
    //let spot = (postID.count - postID.count) + timesRun
    print("id count:", postID.count)
    print("timeRun:", timesRun)
    print("spot is:", timesRun)


   if timesRun >= postsArr.count{
        timesRun = 0
        //tag = 0
    }
   let spot = postsArr[timesRun]

        if spot["postType"] as! Bool == true {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "forSaleListingCell") as! forSaleListingCell
            cell.listingTitle.text = (spot["title"] as! String)
            cell.favCount.text = String(spot["numOfFavs"] as! Int)
            //need to add the relist stuff
            let url = spot["pic"] as! String
            cell.postImage.loadImageWithCache(urlString: url)
            cell.editBtn.tag = timesRun
            cell.commentsBtn.tag = timesRun

            cell.editBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(forSaleEditPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            cell.commentsBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(forSaleCommentsPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            //cell.edit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ClassName.FunctionName.buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
            postHeight = 127.0
            timesRun += 1
            saveArr = postsArr[0]
            //postsArr.remove(at: 0)
            return cell
        }
        else{
            let ISOCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ISOListingCell") as! ISOListingCell
            let url = spot["pic"] as! String
            ISOCell.ISOTitle.text = (spot["title"] as! String)
            ISOCell.editListingBtn.tag = timesRun
            ISOCell.postImage.loadImageWithCache(urlString: url)
            ISOCell.editListingBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ISOEditPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)   //this works with func in this class
            postHeight = 80.0
            timesRun += 1
            saveArr = postsArr[0]
            //postsArr.remove(at: 0)
            return ISOCell
        }

   // }
   // postsArr.append(forSaleArr)
   // postsArr.append(ISOArr)
    //timesRun = 0
    //viewListView.reloadData()
    print("Whya re you here")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "forSaleListingCell") as! forSaleListingCell
    cell.listingTitle.text = "error"
    return cell //a blank cell here.


    }
```

Any tips on how I can achieve this, or better approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Update 1:
Pic 1 is what you initially see, when you pull down the view it goes to pic 2. I want it to look like pic 2 except with sell2 as the third cell. Pic 3 is what happens if you push the cell up out of sight and when it pulls back down it reloads with a new cell. I would just like the cells to stay in order.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.viewListView.separatorStyle = .none
    viewListView.delegate = self
    viewListView.dataSource = self
   // setupCells()
    //viewListView.reloadData()
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) { 
    timesRun = 0
    setupCells()
    viewListView.reloadData()
}

func setupCells(){
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    let userForSale = ref.child("users").child(uid!).child("posts").child("forSalePosts")        
    let userISO = ref.child("users").child(uid!).child("posts").child("ISOPost")
    let user = ref.child("users").child(uid!).child("posts")

    user.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
            return
        }

        for task in snapshot.children {
            guard let taskSnapshot = task as? DataSnapshot else {
                continue
            }

            let id = taskSnapshot.key
            //print(id)

            let snapshot2 = task as! DataSnapshot

            for task2 in snapshot2.children{
                guard let taskSnapshot2 = task2 as? DataSnapshot else {
                    continue
                }
                let arr = taskSnapshot2.value as! [String: Any]



                let pID = taskSnapshot2.key
                self.postID.append(pID)
                print("id is...", id)

                if id == "ISOPost"{

                    let arr2 = taskSnapshot2.value as! [String: Any]
                    let dicPic = arr2["postImages"] as! [String: Any]
                    print("tit", arr2["title"])
                    let holdArr = ["title": arr2["title"]!, "pic": dicPic["ISOUrl1"]!, "postType": arr2["postType"]!, "postID": pID]

                    //print(holdArr["postType"])

                    self.postsArr.append(holdArr)
                }

                if id == "forSalePosts" {

                    let arr2 = taskSnapshot2.value as! [String: Any]
                    let dicPic = arr2["postImages"] as! [String: Any]

                    let holdArr = ["title": arr["title"]!, "numOfFavs": arr["numOfFavs"]!, "pic": dicPic["forSaleUrl1"]!, "postType": arr["postType"]!, "postID": pID]



                    self.postsArr.append(holdArr)

                }

            }



        }


        self.viewListView.reloadData()

    })
```

}

Update 2:

I have updated cellforrowat to indexpath.row instead of timesRun new Screenshots are below.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //print("postArr here", postsArr)
    print(postID)
    //print("******0", postsArr[0])
    //print("******1", postsArr[1])
    //print("******2", postsArr[2])
    print("in tView")
    //timesRun += 1
    //let numPosts = postID.count
    //let spot = (postID.count - postID.count) + timesRun
    print("id count:", postID.count)
    print("timeRun:", timesRun)
    print("spot is:", timesRun)


   if timesRun >= postsArr.count{
        timesRun = 0
        //tag = 0
    }
   let spot = postsArr[indexPath.row]

        if spot["postType"] as! Bool == true {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "forSaleListingCell") as! forSaleListingCell
            cell.listingTitle.text = (spot["title"] as! String)
            cell.favCount.text = String(spot["numOfFavs"] as! Int)
            //need to add the relist stuff
            let url = spot["pic"] as! String
            cell.postImage.loadImageWithCache(urlString: url)
            cell.editBtn.tag = timesRun
            cell.commentsBtn.tag = timesRun

            cell.editBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(forSaleEditPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            cell.commentsBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(forSaleCommentsPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            //cell.edit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ClassName.FunctionName.buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
            postHeight = 127.0
            timesRun += 1
            saveArr = postsArr[0]
            //postsArr.remove(at: 0)
            return cell
        }
        else{
            let ISOCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ISOListingCell") as! ISOListingCell
            let url = spot["pic"] as! String
            ISOCell.ISOTitle.text = (spot["title"] as! String)
            ISOCell.editListingBtn.tag = timesRun
            ISOCell.postImage.loadImageWithCache(urlString: url)
            ISOCell.editListingBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ISOEditPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)   //this works with func in this class
            postHeight = 80.0
            timesRun += 1
            saveArr = postsArr[0]
            //postsArr.remove(at: 0)
            return ISOCell
        }

   // }
   // postsArr.append(forSaleArr)
   // postsArr.append(ISOArr)
    //timesRun = 0
    //viewListView.reloadData()
    print("Whya re you here")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "forSaleListingCell") as! forSaleListingCell
    cell.listingTitle.text = "error"
    return cell //a blank cell here.


    }
```

So image 1 is what you get when you first enter the view listings page. When you pull down the view you get image 2. Which is how I want it to look when you first enter the page. 
[image]

[image]

Update 3
This is all of the code in my file dealing with the tableview. I thought the constraints would fix the problem as I forgot to add them. However, I still have the same problem of having to pull down the view.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(postHeight)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return postID.count //return the num of posts in the users profile.
}
```

Comment: can you show the screenshot , what you get, and what you expect?

Comment: Can you show the *whole* code? where do you set the `tableView.delegate` and `tableView.datasource`, where do you call the `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Seems you layout wasn't correct.

Comment: Whats the behaviour when you scroll up?

Comment: If you scroll up when it has 2 cells then it pulls down the third at index 0 but I would like it at index 2 without having to pull down. Also would like them to stay it order, even if the cell is pushed out of sight if that makes sense.

Comment: OK what is the purpose of timesRun variable?

Comment: Its so I can get the index of where the list is at. Im not able to use a for loop because when you return the cell it starts back at index 0. Would gladly except suggestions on how to achieve this differently.

Comment: if you use indexPath.row instead of timesRun inside cellForRowAt, what changes does it make or remains same? please check

Comment: Ok so I switched let spot = postsArr[timesRun] to let spot = postsArr[indexPath.row]   This has the posts in order however you still have to pull down to get all 3 posts

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show the current situation and remove the pics that we dont need now?

Comment: Ok are you imlementing scrollToRow method in your code? and please add the code for tableview methods, you have removed part of cellForRowAt method

Comment: No I haven't implemented scrolltorow

Comment: Ok , if you put a debug point inside else part, then if indexPath.row is 0, does it enter else part, please see

Comment: Another problem that I think is the constraints that you applied on the tableview, you need to pin you tableview top anchor to the top of containing view

Comment: I have printed out the indexpath.row before the if statement and it starts with indexpath.row == 1 then goes to 2, I put a breakpoint on the else statement and it doesn't run until you pull down the view. Once you pull down the view the indexpath.row prints 0

Comment: @3stud1ant3  Thanks so much for your help! I was able to figure out the problem. (see answer)

Comment: Good work ttorbik,  glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would like to thank 3Stud1ant3 without his help I probably would never have found this.

I initially set the postHeight variable to 0 expecting that the heightForRowAt func isn't called until after the cellforrowat is called where I set the height depending on the cell.  I changed the variable postHeight from 0 to 80.0 and now it is running properly as expected.

```
var postHeight = 80.0


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(postHeight)
}
```